# cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError) || deploy on Ubuntu 12.04 x32

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, rubygems, passenger

I try to deploy my rails app with Nginx, passenger on Ubuntu 12.04 x32. after all things is done, I visit my rails app, but it tell me 'We're sorry, but something went wrong.'.

then I `cat /var/log/nginx/error.log`, I find this lines:

```
Message from application: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
/home/thomas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-  p643/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/home/thomas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:278:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:381:in `running_bundler'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:276:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:99:in `preload_app'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:157:in `<module:App>'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'
```

I use rvm and rbenv

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p643 (2015-02-25 revision 49749) [i686-linux]
$ rbenv versions
system
* 2.0.0-p643 (set by /home/thomas/.rbenv/version)
```

and I hava already installed bundler

```
$ bundler -v
Bundler version 1.9.2
```

and here is my gem env:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.6
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2015-02-25 patchlevel 643) [i686-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/thomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/thomas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/thomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/thomas/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /home/thomas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/thomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643
     - /home/thomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /home/thomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/bin
     - /home/thomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@global/bin
     - /home/thomas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/bin
     - /home/thomas/.rvm/bin
     - /home/thomas/.rbenv/bin
     - /home/thomas/.rbenv/shims
     - /home/thomas/.rbenv/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
     - /usr/games
```

have someone experienced same problem?
thanks

update:
my `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/blog.conf`:
https://gist.github.com/wall2flower/b3f410317585a8803a27
https://gist.github.com/wall2flower/72316e8b437d654e7070

Comment: Paste your /etc/nginx/nginx.conf as well as your site conf.

Comment: I have pated this line to gist, and updated with link : )

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You sure have some PATH issues. Inside the `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`, for passenger, you should be pointing to the ruby version where bundler is installed.

```
passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
passenger_ruby /home/thomas/.rvm/wrappers/default/ruby;
```

You can check this with the command

```
$ which ruby
```

The output of that command should be the one you should enter for `passenger_ruby`

If you haven't installed bundler yet go ahead and run `gem install bundler`

Also make sure that you are setting the environment variable in your server block:

```
server {
  listen 80 default;
  server_name blog.wall2flower.me;
  root /var/www/blog/current/public;
  passenger_enabled on;
}
```

Comment: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#PassengerRuby thanks your help, with above link, I have solved my problems : )

Comment: Thanks for saving my time

Answer (score 5):

You need to genarate `binstubs` to fix the problem:

```
bundle install --binstubs
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
bundle exec passenger start ...
```

Comment: I try: `bundle exec passenger start RAILS_ENV=production`, I get error info:https://gist.github.com/wall2flower/17d0ab44417aeb31aaa9

Comment: try `bundle exec passenger start -e production -d`

Comment: I have try, and now I can visited succed with example.com:3000. : D

Comment: You should change it in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/blog.conf `server_name example.com;` or simply comment this line

Comment: thank your patient, I have solved my problem with this link: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#PassengerRuby  : )

Answer (score 1):

As karlingen notes, the issue is the result of PATH issues, however if you are using RVM, you will want to get your path to the correct ruby another way...

Best thing is to follow Passenger's own guide for finding this info:

https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/nginx/reference/#setting_correct_passenger_ruby_value